# How to use pretty urls with given parameters in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, url

I am a bit in trouble finding the right solution or a plugin which handles my parameters to pretty URLs:

Right now im using links like:

```
<?= add_query_arg('post', get_the_ID(), get_permalink(83)) ?>
<?= add_query_arg('event', $event->ID, get_permalink(158)) ?>
```

Which results in:

```
mydomain.com/post/?post=123
mydomain.com/event/?event=123
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
mydomain.com/post/the-title-of-the-post
mydomain.com/event/the-title-of-the-event
```

I have some more custom post types which are all doing the same.
Everything works perfect, except that I need some pretty URLs

Comment: Have you already set it to nice urls for Permalinks in the Dashboard?

Comment: Are you looking for `get_permalink();` ? Else clarify your desired result.

Comment: @sdcr yes its not possible (or i dont know how) to set up pretty urls like i need them with just setting>permalinks

Comment: @NielsvanRenselaar the question is well clear i guess... its all about the right approach

Comment: @ggzone Do you have nice urls in general apart from your question bits? http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i fixed by doing a "larger" rework... instead of using `get_query_arg` I use `get_permalink` only with the post/custom post ID as parameter.

wordpress itself handles custom post types with slugs inside the url such as:

```
mydomain.com/event/event-title
```

important to know (I didnt)... singleview templates are also handled by wordpress with `single-[customposttype].php` inside the theme folder.

example:

```
custom post type: event
url: mydomain.com/event/event-title
template displayed: [theme]/single-event.php
```